# Почему когда реализуется метод из интерфейса, он должен быть объявлен как public?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Почему когда реализуется метод из интерфейса, он должен быть объявлен как `public`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому, что интерфейс для того и предназначен, что бы гарантировать наличие публичных методов, которыми смогут пользоваться внешние для класса пользователи.

А каким образом будут реализованы эти публичные методы, в том числе, какие они будут использовать методы приватные - это ваше личное дело.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что вы можете создать объект и присвоить его переменной типа интерфейса и это должно гарантировать работу всех методов объявленных в интерфейсе. Например: `IЛетающий летающий = new Самолет(); летающий.Лети();`

Comment: Не уверен о java, но с C# есть еще явные реализации интерфейса, когда метод задекларированный интерфейсом можно вызвать только явно приводя объект к типу интерфейса: `((IЛетающий)самолет).Лети()`